# What to use for video.readyState: video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA or number 4?

Tags: html, video

What is more reliable?:

video.readyState !== video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA

or

video.readyState !== 4

The second form is a poor way of manual coding because, of
today, the constant is 4, but tomorrow is 5. Unpredictable.

But first form is not described anywhere and no one uses it. Why?
Don't all browsers support this?

Yes, there is a callback like canplay(), but in some situation checking a flag is better.

After all, if manual version is good, why whatwg.org spec does keep
"const unsigned short HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA = 4;"
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#the-video-element

Thank you.